# Which Expression trees to be included in a block expression

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm confused on which expression trees need to be added to a blockexpression when wanting code to be executed.

For example, if I have ConditionalExpression, that has a reference to an IsTrue and IsFalse. Do I need to include the expressions that are for IsTrue and IsFalse. or just the Conditional Expression?

Is there a guideline, i.e. how do the IEnumerable of Expressions get executed? Do they get executed in the order they appear in the IEnumerable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression trees work very similarly to C# code: there all the statements inside a block (delimited by `{}`) are executed in order. So, that's exactly how `Expression.Block()` is evaluated too: all the expressions in its `Expressions` collection are evaluated in order. If you want to have a `ConditionalExpression` inside the block, then you shouldn't put them directly into the block (unless you also want them evaluated separately, outside of the `ConditionalExpression`).

Comment: Almost every example I see, they take an Expression, like Expression.New(someType); and then they put it in a lambda, like Expression<Func<object>> ... why is that? Is Expression.New not runnable by itself?

Comment: @user986697 No, it's not, but that's very similar to C#: the expression `new someType()` is not a function you can run by itself, but `() => new someType()` is.

Comment: A `BlockExpression` is also a variable scope, and is the only expression type that lets you declare local variables that can be referenced within the block (or a sub-expression of the block).